# Google Sheets conditional formatting multiple columns with ignoring blank cells

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I want to highlight the cells in E/F/G columns when they exactly match the score in column D, but I want formatting to ignore blank D cells. Can I do this somehow?

[image: screeenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of "Text is exactly..." choose "Custom formula is..."

Then enter the following formula:

`=AND($D2<>"",E2=$D2)`

Comment: Thanks, works flawlessly!

Comment: You're welcome.